# where to find Access Point xap?

Tags: internet-sharing

I have bought Lumia 920 in Czech Republic. It is RM-820 from Canada (operator Regers). It cannot share via Wi-Fi hotspot. Somewhere on internet I find that I must install system app Access Point. But since Microsoft updated Windows Store server to support Windows 10 i can't download xap file of Access Point app for Windows Phone 8.1 anywhere.

Where to find xap of Access Point app (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/pristupovy-bod/9wzdncrfj3ch
)?

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth it to follow some of the XDA posts about flashing your phone with another region's ROM. That way you can might be able to get around the issue of not being able to tether your phone.

Looking at the Store page for Access Point, I don't think it's what you need. I remember having this issue with a HTC 8-series phone that was originally an AT&T device. I ended up accidentally breaking the phone, but I made sure that I could share my Wi-Fi with the next phone I got.